# If a branch in SVN was created against the wrong revision in trunk should I just created the branch?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

If I create a branch in SVN off trunk rev 10 then realized that what I want was rev 9 should i just ditch this branch and create a new one off of rev 9 or is there a way to "rebase" it off of rev 9?

The problem is that in my code I had to rollback some changes and then create a branch for what I now realize is a long/big change.  Since trunk was already updated to use the old code code my incomplete new feature in rev x my branch needs to be created off of rev x-1.  Since my branch was on x+1 what is the easiest way to get it to x-1?

Comment: Ditch the branch and create a new one. If you mess up your SVN repository you will lose much more than you have to win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the branch and re-create it... It's trivially cheap in the repository.